# Adding to another array with triming few characters from string

Tags: php, arrays

`$data` has

```
stdClass Object
(
    [class] => srt-fields
    [rules_field_1] => 1
    [rules_condition_1] => 0
    [rules_value_1] => text
    [rules_field_2] => 3
    [rules_condition_2] => 1
    [rules_value_2] => another_text
    ...
)
```

Now I have another array `$newdata`, I need to have index `$newdata['rules']` so that it should be something like:

```
$newdata['rules'] => array(
             [field] => 1,
             [condition] => 0,
             [value] => text
           ),
           array(
              [field]=> 3,
              [condition] =>1,
              [value] => another_text
           ),
           ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code,

```
$data = [
    "class"             => "srt-fields",
    "rules_field_1"     => "1",
    "rules_condition_1" => "0",
    "rules_value_1"     => "text",
    "rules_field_2"     => "3",
    "rules_condition_2" => "1",
    "rules_value_2"     => "another_text",
];
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $num = filter_var($k, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if (!empty($num)) {
        $result['rules'][$num][(str_replace(['rules_', '_'], '', preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $k)))] = $v;
    }
}
$result['rules'] = array_values($result['rules']);
print_r($result);
```

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) — Filters a variable with a specified filter

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) — Perform a regular expression search and replace

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b0d048ba1b74ec14439ab943c49fdaf6978f475).

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the properties of an object like an array:

```
$newdata['rules']=[];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key,0,6)=='rules_') {
        // split key using '_'
        $parts = explode('_',$key);
        // get the 'name'
        $name = $parts[1] ;
        // get the index (-1 to be 0 based)
        $idx = $parts[2] - 1;
        // store data in new array
        $newdata['rules'][$idx][$name] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($newdata);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [rules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [field] => 1
                    [condition] => 0
                    [value] => text
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [field] => 3
                    [condition] => 1
                    [value] => another_text
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do not use regular expressions for this task -- because it is unnecessary resource overhead.  Explode the keys on underscores, and use the individual components to construct the multi-level keys in your output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sSLY0))

```
$data = (object)[
    "class"             => "srt-fields",
    "rules_field_1"     => "1",
    "rules_condition_1" => "0",
    "rules_value_1"     => "text",
    "rules_field_2"     => "3",
    "rules_condition_2" => "1",
    "rules_value_2"     => "another_text"
];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $bits = explode('_',$key);  // this will produce a 1-element array from `class` and a 3-element array from others
    if (isset($bits[2])) {      // if element [2] exists, then process the qualifying data
        $newdata[$bits[0]][$bits[2]-1][$bits[1]] = $value;
        //                         ^^- make zero based
    }
}
var_export($newdata);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'rules' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'field' => '1',
      'condition' => '0',
      'value' => 'text',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'field' => '3',
      'condition' => '1',
      'value' => 'another_text',
    ),
  ),
)
```

I am using `-1` to make the output keys resemble a zero-based / indexed array.  If your fields might not be consecutively ordered, you can remove the `-1` and write `$newdata['rules'] = array_values($newdata['rules']);` after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
if($j == 0)
{
$newdata['rules'][$i]['field'] = $value;
}
if($j == 1)
{
$newdata['rules'][$i]['condition'] = $value;
}
if($j == 2)
{
$newdata['rules'][$i]['value'] = $value;
$i++;
}
$j++;
if($j > 2)
{
$j = 0;
}
}
```

You can try this code. Please ignore syntax error as I have not tried this code but it should give you the result.